# matplotlib LineCollection misinterprets colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I want to produce a line plot with `matplotlib.pyplot` where each line segment has its assigned color. A color can occur more than once. I use a `LineCollection` and its attribute `cmap` (short for "colormap") to accomplish this, but encounter a problem.
I hope the following code example is reduced enough. The array `data` is just an example, as well as the (in this case periodic) color assignments.

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import numpy as np

n_colors = 8
n_datapoints = 60

# plot legend
data_x = range(n_colors)
data_color = range(n_colors)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 2))
rects = ax.bar(data_x, [1]*n_colors, color=plt.cm.tab20(data_color), alpha = 1)
plt.xticks(data_x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    nrows=1,
    figsize=(15,10),
    squeeze=True,
)

# initialize data to plot
data = np.zeros((n_datapoints,))
for i in range(n_datapoints):
    data[i] = i*i % 20

# prepare data for use in LineCollection
x_y_values = np.vstack((np.arange(n_datapoints), data)).T
x_y_values = x_y_values.reshape(-1,1,2)
segments = np.hstack([x_y_values[:-1], x_y_values[1:]])

# colors for line segments
colors = np.array(list(map(lambda n: n % n_colors, range(n_datapoints))))

# plot

lineCollection = LineCollection(
    segments=segments,
    cmap=plt.cm.tab20,
    **{"linewidths": 1, "alpha": 1},
)
lineCollection.set_array(colors)
ax.add_collection(lineCollection)
ax.autoscale_view()

plt.show()
```

This produces the following two plots:

[image: legend when n_colors==8]
[image: plot when n_colors==8]

As you can see (well, I hope it is visible for you), the colors in the plot do not match the colors in the legend. I expect colors blue, light-blue, orange, light-orange, green, light-green, red, light-red in this order, repeating after the end. What I get is blue, orange, light-green, purple, brown, color-I-don't-know, light-green, light-blue, repeating after the end. Particularly, notice that some of the colors in the plot (brown, for example) are not within the first 8 colors of the colormap `plt.cm.tab20`.
How can this be? Why are the line segments not colored correctly?

When I changed line 6 of the above code from `n_colors = 8` to `n_colors = 5`, the legend still showed what I would expect. Yet the colors of the line plot changed:

[image: legend when n_colors==5]
[image: plot when n_colors==5]

The plot now shows colors blue, light-green, brown, gray, light-blue. So it seems to me that `plt.cm.tab20` is not really a discrete and fixed colormap. But a discrete and fixed colormap is what I want.
What am I doing wrong? How can I get a consistent mapping from {integer between 0 and 20} to {color} for my line plots?

Comment: One workaround would be to pass `color=plt.cm.tab20(data_color)` to your line collection instead of `cmap=plt.cm.tab20` and then just removed the line `lineCollection.set_array(colors)` all together

Comment: @jylls Thanks for the suggestion! If you post it as an answer, I will accept it. (But I think you have a typo. It should be `color=plt.cm.tab20(colors)`. Notice that `data_color` is used in the legend, whereas `colors` is used for the actual plot.

Comment: As you see, I also found another solution (different from jylis'). I think I like jylis' more, but I am definitely not a pro. So if a real Pythonista comes along this post, please share your knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `matplotlib`'s `LineCollection` scales the passed array `colors` onto the real interval [0, 1]. So if only the numbers `0, ..., 7` appear in it, then (I suppose) I get 8 colors from `tab20` which are more or less equally spaced among all 20 colors.
By passing the keyword argument `norm` (documentation can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.Collection)) to `LineCollection`, this can be remedied:

```py
lineCollection = LineCollection(
    segments=segments,
    cmap=plt.cm.tab20,
    norm=mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=19),
    **{"linewidths": 1, "alpha": 1},
)
lineCollection.set_array(colors)
```

Here I added the line `norm=mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=19),` (knowing that my preferred colormap uses indices from 0 to 19).

Comment: Anyone who can elaborate on the internal scaling process: Please go ahead and edit!

Comment: This is great! Good catch!